# Managing (unexpected) Client Specific Configurations the Right Way

Tags: python, configuration, config

**The Situation**

Hi all,

At our company we are building software solutions for a specific niche in Finance. We have a small customer base (20ish) and besides the core functionality, almost every part of the system has been modified for one client or the other. It is important to notice that most of these specifications are difficult to forsee and can completely depend on the clients preference.

I am trying to understand the correct way of dealing with client specificiations in software development. The examples below are taken from problems I encountered during my daily coding in our company.

In the past, typically modifications in the code would be done directly in the function:

```
def do_important_thing(client_name, *args):
  
  # ... do something here
  
  # Hack for the client request:
  if client_name == "client1":
    # ... do something a bit different
  else:
    # ... do it the old way
  
  # ... do a bit more
  
  return
```

This then often turns into longer if/elif/else statements or similar statements on multiple places in the code. For multiple reasons I never believed that this method is optimal. Over time I have managed to remove a good number of these statments from the code base, but they still remain in place especially when the functionality they introduce is more complex.

In newer projects I am trying to stick to client config files and generalise each configuration request from a client:

```
def do_important_thing(client_name: str, client_configurations: dict, *args):

  # ... do something here

  # Hack for the client request:
  if client_configurations.get("use_do_something_different"):
    # ... do something a bit different
  else:
    # ... do it the old way
  
  # ... do a bit more
  
  return
```

With the client configs being loaded at the start of the specific module and moved through the functions:

```
def load_configurations(client_name: str) -> dict:
  """This is usually stored on a database or a dedicated config file"""
  configuration_data = {

    "client1": {"use_do_something_different": True}

  }
  return configuration_data.get(client_name, {})


def main(client_name, *args):
  
  # Load configs
  client_configurations = load_configurations(client_name)
  # Run functions
  do_important_thing(client_name, client_configurations, *args)
```

This worked so far pretty okay (happy if anyone can provide improvements), but I am struggeling with more complex functioniality.

**The Problem**

Let's say I have a certain module like a report generator

```
class ReportGenerator:
   ...
   def generate():
   """abstract method"""

class DefaultReportGenerator(ReportGenerator):
   ...
   def generate():
   """default implementation"""
   ...
```

And now a client wishes to completely change the report and it can't be solved by just changing the configurations. Then I would create a new function or a class based on the problem. E.g.

```
class Client1ReportGenerator(DefaultReportGenerator):
   ...
   def generate():
   """client1 implementation"""
   ...
```

And also implement the mapping to this class into the client config file?

```
def main(client_name):
  
  configuration_data = {

    "client1": {
      "report_generator": Client1ReportGenerator
    }
  }

  client_configuration = configuration_data.get(client_name, {})

  # pick engine
  report_generator = client_configuration.get(client_name, DefaultReportGenerator)
  # run report
  report_generator().generate()
```

I would be really happy for any kind of feedback and also any opinions on the three questions below:

1. Is there a big downside with the config file solution?
2. For a large code base with different modules, would you keep one central config file or config files for each module?
3. Is there a better way of managing the mix of a classic config file and bespoke functionality mapped to a client (especially since it's difficult to save config files of the last version into a database)

Thanks!!

As described above, I tried moving to hard coded config files in each module to have configurations and function mappings in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I did something sort-of-similar to what you want, but I used a different technology (code generation instead of runtime configuration files) and I did this for applications containing about 3000 to 5000 lines of code, which might be much smaller than the size of applications you are working with. In other words, what I am about to describe may not be suitable for your needs. But I will explain my approach anyway in the hope that it might provide you with some food for thought.

Read this [chapter](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-practical-usage-guide/code-generation.html#sec15) from one of the manuals of Config4* (a configuration-file parser library I developed). Now forget the focus on generating application code from CORBA IDL. Instead, imagine a configuration file that contains lots of `name=value` statements, where the values might be booleans, enum values, and perhaps lists/tables/dictionaries. Do not have variables that identify customers by name; instead, have variables that specify particular choices for generating code. For example, instead of `customer=[name of a specific customer]`, use `do_important_thing_approach=[name of approach used by one or more customers]`. Some of the variables might be used to direct code generation at a coarse granularity, such as implementations of entire functions/classes. Some of the other variables might be used for finer granularity code generation, such as generating a few lines of code to execute if a particular event occurs.

Your code generator should do the following:

- Use print statements to generate code. I'm not a Python programmer, but I vaguely recall that Python permits multi-line string literals, complete with the ability to replace placeholders in a string with values. You might use that approach. Alternatively, perhaps you can find a template engine.
- Parse the configuration file and use values in it to control if-then-else statements surrounding the print statements.
- The configuration file should also specify the names of code segment files. The code generator should be coded with the ability to copy-and-paste a code segment into the output being generated at appropriate places. For example, when generating a `foo()` function, if there is a code segment called `foo()` then it is copied into the output file; otherwise, configuration variables can be used to customize some aspects of the generation of the `foo()` function.
- You will use a separate configuration file (and its associated code segment files) for each customer. The code generation should take the name of a configuration file as a command-line argument. Thus you will run `my-code-generator.py customer1.cfg` to generate code for customer1's application, and run `my-code-generator.py customer2.cfg` to generate code for customer2's application.

The above approach will enable you to create customized versions of the application for each customer.

My experience with using the above approach can be summed up as follows:

- A typical generated application was between 3000 and 5000 lines of code.
- The code generator was about 10,000 lines of code. This consisted mostly of large print statements, plus some if-then-else statements (to select which print statements to execute) that were driven by values in the configuration file.
- The configuration file and its code segment files were typically about 300 to 500 lines in size for each variation of the application being generated.
- In essence, it took more up-front work to write the code generator than to hand-write one variation of the application, but we reached the break-even point on effort once we had generated 3 or 4 variations of the application. Eventually, we got up to generating 20+ variations of the application.
- The "code generation driven by configuration and code segments" approach helped enormously with managing complexity and fixing bugs, so over time the quality of the generated applications improved.